# Openstack deployment fails at 99% Configure Availability Zones

Tags: juju, openstack, landscape, ceph, openstack-autopilot

Using the newly released Landscape deploy for Openstack, I've gotten to 99% completion, with 1 failure citing Configure Availability Zones.

error I have received

Unsupported Scheme: ''

I'm going to guess it has something to do with Ceph, and could very well be a bug but I am unsure where to look for some clue on how to fix, or whether I can force the install to finish.

Answer (score 1):

can you please show us the contents of /var/log/landscape/job-handler-1.log on the landscape/0 unit? It should have a more complete description of what went wrong.